# Core Data and custom attribute type

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3

Evening,

I'm trying to build an Entity A with a property x of type T.

T is an enum that I created.

---

How should I set xcdatamodel to use a custom type for an attribute?

**My current set up is:**

```
attribute x, type: Undefined, CustomClass: T.
```

**But I have the error:**

> x .... core data must have a defined type.

**Specific Purpose:**

x is a "mood" attribute with 3 different moods possible, that's why I choose the enum.

Comment: May I know the specific purpose for this custom attribute type? `Transformable` should provide what you are looking for.

Comment: Think about what *defined type* is supposed to be. It's one of the types in the popup menu or a self-defined type via transformable. The usual way to use enums in Core Data is to map the cases to `Int` or `String` with a computed property.

Comment: @iOSAppDev This is the specific purpose: I have a "mood" attribute with 3 different moods possible, that's why I choose the enum. So should I use Transofrmable?

Comment: @vadian I understand what you mean, but I don't know how, could you explain better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to bend Core Data managed objects to accept enums, especially in this simple case.

Just use a standard `String` attribute, call it `mood` and do the enum evaluation and appropriate logic when you read and write to it. This will result in human readable, intuitive code.

**Edit**: sample implementation

```
enum Mood: String { case happy, ok, sad }
class Person: NSManagedObject {
    var mood: String?
}

// set
person.mood = Mood.happy.rawValue
// get
let aPersonsMood = Mood(rawValue: person.mood!)
```

Comment: thank, would you give me an example of this implementation?

Answer (score 13):

There is a type called `Transformable` in CoreData that's designed specifically for handling types that are not natively supported.

Basically this type will help you automatically serialize a non supported type to a `Data` object before storing it in the database, and deserialize it when it is retrieved.
This is great for storage, but it can become tricky to implement when it comes to queries (because you queries are now using the raw `Data` used by the database).

---

An easier way to implement this is to use a computed property that hides the raw value (which will usually be a `String` or an `Int`).

Here is how you can implement it :

```
enum Mood: String
{
    case happy
    case sad
}

class MyObject: NSManagedObject
{
    @NSManaged private var rawMood: String?

    var mood: Mood? {
        get {
            if let rawMood = self.rawMood {
                return Mood(rawValue: rawMood)
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
        set {
            self.rawMood = newValue?.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Remember that when you are adding contraint on a query you need to use `rawMood` and pass it a `String`. Core Data has no knowledge of a `mood` property.